# Adding tick marks to one y axis of a plot with two y axes

Tags: r, plot

My data:

```
a = c(5,2,1)
b = c(75,82,36)
c <- c("Baseline", "FW1", "FW2")
```

My code:

```
finyrNum <- (1:3)
twoord.plot(finyrNum, a, finyrNum, b,
            type=c("bar", "l"), lylim = c(0, 7),
            ylab="Days Used", rylab="Amount", xlab="Time Point",
            lcol=32, rcol=4, do.first="plot_bg()", xticklab=c)
```

This creates a plot that looks like the following: 
[image: Plot]

How do I change the left y axis so that there are tick marks that go to 7, rather than stop at 5?

Also - how do I change the margins so there is room between the boundary of the plot and the bars?

Comment: The code does not run because the object `finyrNum` is not defined. Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: sorry - I edited the original post to define finyrNum. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
twoord.plot(finyrNum, a, finyrNum, b,
            type=c("bar", "l"), lylim = c(0, 7), lytickpos = 1:7,
            ylab="Days Used", rylab="Amount", xlab="Time Point",
            lcol=32, rcol=4, do.first="plot_bg()", xticklab=c)
```

The `lytickpos` was what you're looking for. Check out the documentation for `twoord.plot`, there's a lot of graphical options to explore.

Comment: thanks! Does anyone know how to change the margins so they're not against the boundary?

Comment: that is - so there is space between the bars in the graph and the boundary of the plot...